# Android get gmail email subject from notification

Tags: android, email, notifications, gmail, listener

i would like to read the subject of a new received email (gmail) from an android notification.

I think i have to use a NotificationListenerService running in background, catch the notification of new email in real time, and read the subject from that.

But how can i read the subject or a part of body text? Is it possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to get something working and if you have a specific problem, post a question about that.

Comment: it's possible, check out notification big content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that catches notifications and puts them into a text file.  I only made this for development purposes so I could see how each app populates the notifications but it should show you how to do it.

```
    @Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

    new Store().execute(sbn);
}

private class Store extends AsyncTask<StatusBarNotification, Integer, Long> {

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(StatusBarNotification... params) {

        String temp = "";

        StatusBarNotification sbn = params[0];

        Notification not = sbn.getNotification();
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();

        // dump all the android notifications
        if (pack.startsWith("com.android")) return null;
        if (pack.startsWith("com.estrongs")) return null;
        if (pack.startsWith("com.motorola")) return null;

        count++;
        if (not.category != null)
            temp += "Category: " + not.category.toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "Category = null \n";

        if (not.tickerText != null)
            temp += "TickerText: " + not.tickerText.toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "TickerText = null \n";

        temp += "Key: " + sbn.getKey() + "\n" + "ID: " + sbn.getId() + "\n";

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-kk:mm:ss:SSS");
        Long ptime = sbn.getPostTime();
        temp += "Post time: " + format.format(ptime) + "\n";
        Long nottime = not.when;
        temp += "When: " + format.format(nottime) + "\n";

        temp += "Extras..." + "\n";
        Bundle bun = not.extras;
        if (bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT) != null)
            temp += "BigText: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_BIG_TEXT).toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "BigText = null \n";

        if (bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_SUMMARY_TEXT) != null)
            temp += "SummaryText: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_SUMMARY_TEXT).toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "SummaryText = null \n";

        if (bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_INFO_TEXT) != null)
            temp += "InfoText: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_INFO_TEXT).toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "InfoText = null \n";

        if (bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT) != null)
            temp += "Text: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT).toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "Text = null \n";

        if (bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT) != null)
            temp += "SubText: " + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT).toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "SubText = null \n";

        if (bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE) != null)
            temp += "Title:" + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE).toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "Title = null \n";

        if (bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE_BIG) != null)
            temp += "Big Title:" + bun.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE_BIG).toString() + "\n";
        else
            temp += "Big Title = null \n";

        temp += "Fields... \n";

        CharSequence[] lines = bun.getCharSequenceArray(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES);
        if (lines != null) {
            for (CharSequence line : lines) {
                temp += "line: " + line.toString() + "  \n";
            }
        } else {
            temp += " no lines... \n";
        }

        file = new File(save, pack + count + ".txt");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(temp.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "File written", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Notice I send the SBN to a background thread.  The listener does not like much of anything in its thread.  Also, the listener can be tricky with the debugger.  I found that you need to disable the app in Android settings -> Sound & Notification -> Notification Access before you update the app.  Then you can re-enable it once a package update is installed.

Hope that helps.